# What is the fastest way to compare every value [i] against another value [j] in separate lists/arrays?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, loops

I have 2 lists of index i and j (really I have 4 lists but they both are time and position with the same index). I need to compare every single value in i with every single value in j i.e. i=0 vs j=0,1,2,3... then i=1 vs j=0,1,2,3... I am comparing times and positions of both i and j so I have it currently set up 2 different ways but neither are as fast as I would like. I have a very simple nested loop like:

```
for i in range(0,len(a1)):
    for j in range(0,len(b1)):
        if ((a1[i] <= b1[j] + 100) & (a1[i] >= b1[j] - 100)):
            if angdist(a2.ra[i],a2.dec[i],b2.ra[j],b2.dec[j]) <= error[i]*u.degree: 
                print 'Found one that occurred at', a1[i]                    
                print 'It was located at', a2[i], 'with a likelihood value of', L
```

L is a value that depends on both i and j index but I figured it would be easier to make it simple here. This method takes about 13 seconds per loop which is really slow.

I also have a method that uses boolean arrays to mask one of the arrays so I only get have to "march through" 1 large array and 1 tiny array to cut back processing time.

```
for i in range(0,len(a1)):
        bool_time = (b1 < a1[i] + 100) & (b1 > a1[i] - 100)
        angsep = angdist(a2.ra[i], a2.dec[i], b2[bool_time], b2.dec[bool_time])
        bool_ang = (angsep <= error[i]*u.degree)
        b_err = b3[bool_time][bool_ang]
        b_en = b3[bool_time][bool_ang]
        for x, y in zip(b_en,b_err):
            print 'Found one that occurred at', a1[i]                    
            print 'It was located at', a2[i], 'with a likelihood value of', L
```

This method takes about 2.5s per loop but I need to run these things with scrambled data thousands to millions of times so a lower time, under 0.1s would be ideal.

Since I am comparing time and position I have thought about a method which would only compare a1[i] vs the first few j indexes in b1 and then stop after it gets beyond the range (100 seconds). My problem was coming up with a way to start and stop this loop without excluding indices. The stopping part is easy but the starting part is confusing to me.

For context all the a arrays are about 400 indexes and the b arrays are about 14000 indexes but this number will be increasing to maybe over 100 thousand when I get more data.

Comment: Could you add some exemplaric inputs? The terms list and array are often used interchangably (even though they aren't). To actually help you it would be good to know with what kind of "array"s you have.

Comment: Another question: Are you using `astropy`? And what is `angdist`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I am using a few different things, a1 and b1 are Datetime object lists, a2 and b2 are astropy SkyCoord object lists in the first method. In the second method I had converted a1 and b1 to seconds from some arbitrary starting point and then turned it into an array of floats but a2 and b2 are astropy SkyCoords object lists. b_err and b_en are pandas DataFrame object lists. angdist is a function that just measures distance between the 2 points. I know its a bit all over the place but I am fairly new to coding and am learning as I go.

Comment: Since this is an optimization question you can't expect to get accurate answers without providing your data (or data like it - most of the time you can use [`np.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) to create some random arrays then pass them to `astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord` or `pandas.DataFrame` or convert them to lists using `.tolist()`). If one can actually reproduce the code and timings then it's much easier (and more reliable) to answer the question. The more data you provide the more accurate answers will be. :)

Comment: Ah, and you can just [edit] the question. That's better (and more readable) than to put them in comments. Of course you can always add a comment saying "I adressed your questions in the question". :)

Comment: BTW, `&` is bit-wise AND.  Your `if` should use `and`.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280361/list-comparing-techniques-for-faster-performance

Comment: When you say, `array` is that just another name for `list`, or are you using something like `array.array` or `numpy`?